# How to populate DataGridView with textbox and combobox with comboboxcells having different value lists

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have three columns , textbox, combobox and textbox in that order:

```
this.columnLocalName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.columnLocalAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
this.columnLocalPort = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
```

And they are in turn in a datagridview like so:

```
this.dataGridViewLocalProfile.Columns.AddRange(
new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
                    this.columnLocalName,
                    this.columnLocalAddress,
                    this.columnLocalPort});
```

Later on I will try to add different values to each combobox cell like so:

```
foreach (profile in localProfile.List)
{
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell =(DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
(dataGridViewLocalProfile.Rows[dataGridViewLocalProfile.Rows.Count - 1].
Cells["columnLocalAddress"]);

cell.Items.Clear();
cell.Items.Add(profile.Address.ToString());

dataGridViewLocalProfile.Rows.Add(
new string[] { profile.Name, profile.Address, profile.Port });
}
```

This results in a datagrid with the first column and last column populated and the comboboxcolumn empty. with an dataerror which I handle. The message is:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
```

I have read through most of the post, but can not find a solution to this.

I have tried with setting the datasource like so:

```
cell.DataSource = new string[] { profile.Address };
```

still getting empty comboboxcolumn with an dataerror saying

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
```

I think this is extra tricky since I add different values for each comboboxcell.

Can anyone, please help me as to how i can make this work.

/Best

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but here's the solution anyways.

The problem is in the `foreach` loop.  The `ComboBox` cell from the last existing row is populated with an item.  But then, a whole new row is added using the current `profile` object:

```
dataGridViewLocalProfile.Rows.Add( new string[] { profile.Name, profile.Address, profile.Port });
```

The items for the `ComboBox` cell in this new row is empty, therefore `profile.Address` *is not valid*.  Change the `foreach` loop to look like this and you're gold:

```
foreach (Profile p in this.localProfile)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
  row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

  DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[1];
  cell.Items.Clear();
  cell.Items.Add(p.Address);

  row.Cells[0].Value = p.Name;
  row.Cells[1].Value = p.Address;
  row.Cells[2].Value = p.Port;
  this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```